# Error 404 when loading subfolder on Google app engine

Tags: html, google-app-engine

I have a website with an `index.html` as a homepage that works fine, but I want to create a website structure with subfolders, so I created a folder named "team".

Inside "team", I put an `index.html` file with the team information. When I load [www.mysite.com/team/index.html](http://www.mysite.com/team/index.html) it works fine, but if I load [www.mysite.com/team](http://www.mysite.com/team) I get a 404 error.

How do I fix this to load the `index.html` inside the subfolder automatically??

I am using the Google app engine as a server, I upload files with the Google app engine launcher and use some Python files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In you `app.yaml`, define your static file handlers like this:

```
…
handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static
- url: /(.*?)/?
  static_files: \1/index.html
  upload: (.*?)/index.html
…
```

Note that because you define your website structure like this, you won't be able to access any other file except the `index.html` files. For example, if you go to `/images/logo.png`, App Engine would try to serve that from the static file `images/logo.png/index.html`.

To fix that problem, you'll need to put all your static files in a different subdirectory (`/static` in the above example), and serve that as a `static_dir`. Then you should reference your files from the `index.html` files as `/static/images/logo.png`, etc.

**UPDATE**: I'll paste your `app.yaml` here because you cannot format it correctly in the comment:

```
handlers:
- url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css|php|xml))
  static_files: \1
  upload: (.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css|php|xml))

- url: /robots.txt
  static_files: robots.txt
  upload: robots.txt 

- url: /favicon.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon.ico

- url: .*
  script: main.py

- url: /static
  static_dir: static

- url: /(.*?)/?
  static_files: \1/index.html
  upload: (.*?)/index.html
```

Your problem is that the `- url: .*` directive catches everything so the bottom two handlers are never reached.

Also, you should consider using an application reference in the `script` instead of the file name. Providing the script file name is deprecated.

Comment: I have an error: Error: Server Error

The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
If the problem persists, please report your problem.....

my app.yaml:
handlers:
- url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css|php|xml))
  static_files: \1
  upload: (.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css|php|xml))

- url: /robots.txt
  static_files: robots.txt
  upload: robots.txt 

- url: /favicon.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon.ico

- url: .*
  script: main.py

- url: /static
  static_dir: static

- url: /(.*?)/?
  static_files: \1/index.html
  upload: (.*?)/index.html

Comment: Ok that works, but now the main page doesn't load:
Error: Not Found
The requested URL / was not found on this server.

Comment: Do you only want to serve the main page on `/`? Then just move back up the rule and rename the `url` pattern to `/`. If you want the same paths to match both static files and your handler, that's going to involve more complex rules.

Comment: I have all html files in root directory, but google doesn't index correctly my sitelinks, so i need to create a website sitemap with some structure, so i want to put every "menu item" of my page inside a folder to make a tree directory structure. so i need to load www.mysite.com ->index.html; www.mysite.com/team -> /team/team.html; www.mysite.com/team/ -> /team/team.html and www.mysite.com/team/team.html -> /team/team.html.
At first i tried to rename team.html to index.html but with no luck.

Comment: Serving index files for directories doesn't work like that on App Engine (at least not as you would do in e.g. an Apache config file). All you can do is work with URL routes and regexes and work out how to structure your handlers.

Comment: Thank you @attila o. i will find another way to create a structure sitemap.