# Subdirectory pages not found static site hosted on Google Cloud Storage Bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gridsome

I'm setting up a static site on a Google Cloud Storage Bucket with Loadbalancer. The site gets generated with Gridsome and then the dist folder gets saved in the bucket.

I have set the index and error with gsutil like in the [documentation]: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/web

Now I am facing a problem with how every url for accessing subdirectories gets redirected to dir/index.html. This is desired behavior, the dir/index.html page even exists in the bucket. But I still get a 404 - not found.

**If I do a curl to the url subdir/index.html I get the HTML**

[image: Image of bucket structure]

Answer (score 1):

I do not know exactly how you are testing your subfolder but I think this link can help you with your issue [Error 404 when loading subfolder on GCS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20402020/error-404-when-loading-subfolder-on-google-app-engine). In addition, you maybe must to take a look here [How subdirectories work](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/HowSubdirectoriesWork).

Comment: When I curl to the subdir/index.html it returns the HTML. It is just a static site hosted on a bucket, cant use a app.yaml there!

Answer (score 1):

Based on [How subdirectories work](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/HowSubdirectoriesWork) on GCS, when browser request URL `http://www.example.com/dir` it will be redirect (301) to The object `http://www.example.com/dir/index.html` on content served.

My assumption is there is no route `http://www.example.com/dir/index.html` on Vue (vue-router). So it will be throw to Not Found 404 page.

The simple solution is try to change all subdirectories link from

`http://www.example.com/dir`, `http://www.example.com/about` etc, to

`http://www.example.com/dir/`, `http://www.example.com/about/`

It will not redirect to 404 page when you request subdirectories url or reload the browser. But we all know that it's not best practices.